# Large INSERT INTO SELECT [..] FROM gradually gets slower

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, query-performance

I've written a program that does a large `INSERT` in batches of 100,000 and [shows its progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDY5l.png).

The source table contains 2.5GB of data:

```
CREATE TABLE wikt.text (
    old_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    old_text MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
    old_flags TINYBLOB NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (old_id),
    KEY old_id (old_id)

)   ENGINE=INNODB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=23565544
    DEFAULT CHARSET=binary;

CREATE INDEX old_id ON text (old_id);
```

This is the destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE domains.dictionary_language (
    text_id     INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    english     TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (text_id),
    KEY         english (english)

)   ENGINE=INNODB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=23565544;
```

This is the query being run in batches of 100k:

```
INSERT INTO domains.dictionary_language
    SELECT      old_id,
                IF(old_text LIKE '%==English==%', 1, 0)

    FROM        wikt.text

    LIMIT       {batch}, 100000;
```

The query is getting slower and slower. <strike>The first 1 million records inserted in 8 minutes. After that, records #1.2m - #1.3m *alone* took 7 mins. Now #2.3m - #2.4m just finished in 15 mins.</strike>

Here's the log of how long each batch of 100k takes to import.

As you can see, the first 12 batches (1.2 million records) insert in < 1 minute each. After that, the performance drops, with each batch taking a bit longer than the last!

```
24/11/2013 19:18:40 Ready

24/11/2013 19:18:42 Dictionary import started from Wiktionary
24/11/2013 19:18:42 Records:    3,729,613
24/11/2013 19:18:42 Batches of: 100,000

24/11/2013 19:19:11 Batch 1 finished in 00:00:29.3146767
24/11/2013 19:19:33 Batch 2 finished in 00:00:22.2142706
24/11/2013 19:19:41 Batch 3 finished in 00:00:07.6104353
24/11/2013 19:19:53 Batch 4 finished in 00:00:12.7057267
24/11/2013 19:20:08 Batch 5 finished in 00:00:14.9248537
24/11/2013 19:20:25 Batch 6 finished in 00:00:16.9849715
24/11/2013 19:20:43 Batch 7 finished in 00:00:17.7930177
24/11/2013 19:20:49 Batch 8 finished in 00:00:06.2453572
24/11/2013 19:21:07 Batch 9 finished in 00:00:17.2549869
24/11/2013 19:21:38 Batch 10 finished in 00:00:31.4577993
24/11/2013 19:22:02 Batch 11 finished in 00:00:23.7003556
24/11/2013 19:22:17 Batch 12 finished in 00:00:15.4078813
24/11/2013 19:23:40 Batch 13 finished in 00:01:22.9637452
24/11/2013 19:25:25 Batch 14 finished in 00:01:44.8639979
24/11/2013 19:27:40 Batch 15 finished in 00:02:15.1387295
24/11/2013 19:30:07 Batch 16 finished in 00:02:26.7553939
24/11/2013 19:33:01 Batch 17 finished in 00:02:54.3109701
24/11/2013 19:36:17 Batch 18 finished in 00:03:15.8252006
24/11/2013 19:39:57 Batch 19 finished in 00:03:40.1275906
24/11/2013 19:44:28 Batch 20 finished in 00:04:30.3824650
24/11/2013 19:49:48 Batch 21 finished in 00:05:20.6873423
24/11/2013 19:55:45 Batch 22 finished in 00:05:56.7674059
24/11/2013 20:02:37 Batch 23 finished in 00:06:52.0925703
24/11/2013 20:10:32 Batch 24 finished in 00:07:54.8921622
24/11/2013 20:18:12 Batch 25 finished in 00:07:39.9433072
24/11/2013 20:26:34 Batch 26 finished in 00:08:21.4696824
24/11/2013 20:36:00 Batch 27 finished in 00:09:26.3163915
24/11/2013 20:45:07 Batch 28 finished in 00:09:07.1472950
24/11/2013 20:54:48 Batch 29 finished in 00:09:41.0222326
24/11/2013 21:04:19 Batch 30 finished in 00:09:31.2316726
24/11/2013 21:14:35 Batch 31 finished in 00:10:15.3521962
24/11/2013 21:25:10 Batch 32 finished in 00:10:34.9583176
24/11/2013 21:36:27 Batch 33 finished in 00:11:17.6047568
24/11/2013 21:47:52 Batch 34 finished in 00:11:24.3261412
24/11/2013 21:59:32 Batch 35 finished in 00:11:40.2410515
24/11/2013 22:12:31 Batch 36 finished in 00:12:59.1605654
24/11/2013 22:26:12 Batch 37 finished in 00:13:40.9209540
24/11/2013 22:40:12 Batch 38 finished in 00:13:59.8160347

24/11/2013 22:40:12 Dictionary import finished
```

It's getting slower and slower with each batch of 100k! Why? Here's the [EXPLAIN output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXIJR.png).

The server itself is tuned up with a 4GB buffer pool etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The large offsets can have this effect. I would try to remove the offset and use only `LIMIT 10000`:

```
INSERT INTO domains.dictionary_language
  (text_id, english)
    SELECT      t.old_id,
                IF(t.old_text LIKE '%==English==%', 1, 0)

    FROM        wikt.text AS t
      JOIN      ( SELECT COALESCE(MAX(text_id), 0) AS offset
                  FROM domains.dictionary_language
                ) AS m
                ON  t.old_id > m.offset

    ORDER BY    t.old_id
    LIMIT       100000;
```

Comment: wont this insert only the first 100000records?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand only if you run it once. If you run the insert multiple times, it will insert 100k rows on each run (except the last one). The join `ON t.old_id > m.offset` takes care that every time we get new rows to insert.